# How can I upgrade from Primeng 11.0.1 to the most recent version?

Tags: angular, primeng

Unable to upgrade, getting so much error.

I tried this command, but it didn't work:

npm update primeng --save

Regrettably, this command did not yield the desired results. I'm in search of a comprehensive solution and would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance that can be provided to address this problem effectively.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked:

```
npm install primeng@12 --save
```